# What is the size of a Sulfate ion?

Tags: organic-chemistry, ions

In terms of nanometers, what would the size be of an individual sulfate ion in solution?

Would its size exceed 0.5 nm? Enough to displace something that is held together with a gap of 0.35 nm?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. If you want to learn more about how this site works, the short [tour] is a good place to start. Best of luck with your question!

Answer (score 3):

The radius of a sulfate ion is  0.242 +/- 0.007 nm. ([Yirhak Marcus. *Chem. Rev.* **1988,** *88*, 1475-1498.](https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/cr00090a003))
In order to know if it would displace something could you tell us what exactly you are trying to displace?